# Integration field mapping

Tags: api, integration

Currently there is an integration in place with a 3rd party .

Fields flow directly from VF page to 3rd party .

Scenario- A new field is added to the VF Page

Question - Who is going to decide (SFDC or middleware) how this field is going to be mapped ? Should middleware provide the canonical path against the SFDC field ?

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends upon how flexible the platforms are. As you use middleware, you would have more control on the fields mapping once new field is added into SF VF. I would suggest you to get in the call with the Middleware/3rd party about how to handle such scenes. It overall depends on flexibility of platform and integrating in such a way that other code doesn't break.